# How do you delete media messages from viber chat?

Tags: delete, media-files, viber-messenger

If media files are deleted from within chat, they are still in the gallery. If they are deleted from the gallery, they are still in the chat as thumbnails, but says "file not found" if clicking on them. Basically one has to delete them in both places - in chat and in gallery. So, how do you delete both instances at once?